# Print jsonp object properties with a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, jsonp

I'm getting the following object via jsonp. This is the structure:

```js
     "item1": {
        "child1": {
            "nr": 123,
            "money": "USD",
            "Date": "12.12.2016, 17:00",
             "asw1": 13,
            "SpecialField": 33,
            "another": 11,
            "climbedSince": 1,
            "rfeeew": 0,
            "dfffe": 10
        },
        "child2": {
            "nr": 123,
            "money": "EUR",
            "Date": "01.01.2017, 17:00",
             "asw1": 11,
            "SpecialField": 11,
            "another": 11,
            "climbedSince": 1,
            "rfeeew": 0,
            "dfffe": 10
        }
    },
    "item2": {
        "child1": {
            "nr": 552,
            "money": "USD",
            "Date": "12.4.2016, 13:00",
             "asw1": 13,
            "SpecialField": 33,
            "another": 44,
            "climbedSince": 1,
            "rfeeew": 0,
            "dfffe": 10
        },
        "child2": {
            "nr": 343,
            "money": "EUR",
            "Date": "01.01.2017, 17:00",
             "asw1": 11,
            "SpecialField": 67,
            "another": 11,
            "climbedSince": 1,
            "rfeeew": 0,
            "dfffe": 10
        }
    }
```

This is my code.

```js
<script>
  function getApiData(tld, callback) {
 $.ajax({
  url: 'https://www.website.com/api',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {
   callback(data);
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function() {
   console.error('Could not get lottery jackpots!');
  }
 });
}
function drawApiData() {
 var now = new Date();
 getApiData('com', function(theStuff){
  $.each(theStuff, function( id, value ) {
   var checkStuff=[];
   if($.inArray(id, checkStuff)==-1){
    checkStuff.push(id); 
    $('#main2').append('Field: '+id+'<br/');
    }
  });
 });
}
drawAllData();
 </script>
```

I would like to print (append) on the screen couple of values with a for loop, for as many items the object has (it's not static, but the structure is always the same).

I can print item1, item2 but I cannot manage to access the 2nd level.

What I would like to print is for example the time from "Date" + the "SpecialField".

Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Comment: `$.each()` method is for *Iterate over a jQuery object* not for regular objects

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
var container = $("#main2");
var append = (obj) => {
  //do something with obj object
  container.append('My date: '+obj.Date);
};
for(var parent of theStuff){
  for(var child of parent){
    append(child);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm not sure I understand your for loop though. Would you be so kind to elaborate a little?